# Advanced SQL Update query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a sql update query for a stored procedure but I'm getting lost in trying to figure out how to to do it.

Here is what I'm trying do:

The table I'm wanting to update has 3 columns: product_item_id, rel_product_item_id, and sequence. This table is called "ProductRelationship".

I also have another table called ProductDetails.  This table also contains a column called product_item_id as well as a column called "sku".

I want the user to be able input the sku number that updates the rel_product_item_id column with the corresponding product_item_id number from the ProductDetails table.

So on the front-end, the user is inputting a sku, but in the backend, the product_item_id number is getting updated in the database based on the sku the user entered.

Basically its cross-referencing the sku number on the details table, finding the appropiate product item id number and inserting that id number in the table instead of the user-inputted sku number.

Comment: How do you know which ProductRelationship row should be updated? I understand how to choose the rel_product_item_id, just don't know which product_item_id gets updated.

Comment: Oh sorry should have mentioned that.  That row is getting updated by a set value in the page.  basically its looking a control on a page and using that value automatically so the user never knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update ProductRelationship
    set rel_product_item_id = (select product_item_id 
                                   from ProductDetails 
                                   where sku = @UserInput)
    where product_item_id = @ValueSetOnPage
```

Comment: Thats makes sense, but when I try to execute it fails with:"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'rel_product_item_id', table 'DD_SITE.dbo.ProductRelationship'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails."

Comment: so it seems as if even though we are querying ProductDetails just fine, its not returning the rel_product_item_id?

Comment: Your NULL error would indicate that @UserInput doesn't correspond to the sku column for any ProductDetails record in this case.

Comment: NEVERMIND.  This was my fault.  It was a problem with my stored proc.  I had the sku variable set to varchar(1) when it needed to be varchar(15).  Thanks!!!